# How can I scrape multiple search result page of amazon using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape multiple search result page details from Amazon? For the 1st page, it is working properly but for other pages, it is not working properly and the results are also not the same.

YML file details :

```
products:
    css: 'div[data-component-type="s-search-result"]'
    xpath: null
    multiple: true
    type: Text
    children:
        title:
            css: 'h2 a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'
            xpath: null
            type: Text
        url:
            css: 'h2 a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'
            xpath: null
            type: Link
        rating:
            css: 'div.a-row.a-size-small span:nth-of-type(1)'
            xpath: null
            type: Attribute
            attribute: aria-label
        reviews:
            css: 'div.a-row.a-size-small span:nth-of-type(2)'
            xpath: null
            type: Attribute
            attribute: aria-label
        price:
            css: 'span.a-price:nth-of-type(1) span.a-offscreen'
            xpath: null
            type: Text
```

This is the function I am using

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 
import json 
from time import sleep
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('search_result.yml')

def scrape(url):  

    headers = {
        'dnt': '1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'referer': 'https://www.amazon.in/',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }

    # Download the page using requests
    print("Downloading %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Simple check to check if page was blocked (Usually 503)
    if r.status_code > 500:
        if "To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact" in r.text:
            print("Page %s was blocked by Amazon. Please try using better proxies\n"%url)
        else:
            print("Page %s must have been blocked by Amazon as the status code was %d"%(url,r.status_code))
        return None
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create 
    return e.extract(r.text)
data = scrape('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=mobile')
print(data)
```

For the first page, it is working properly but when clicking on the next page the url is also being dynamically changed including the qid.

Example of 2nd link: 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=mobile&page=2&qid=1602337497&ref=sr_pg_2'

when I am trying to run a loop I am making the url like this : 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=mobile&page={}'.format(i).

It is also giving me the result but not the same result what I am getting when I click on the link.

How can I scrape multiple page of amazon search result?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this, it works pretty fine, just use a loop on page number:

```
import requests as r
import json

page_number = 1
my_url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s/query?k=mobile&page={}&qid=1604103880&ref=sr_pg_{}'.format(page_number, page_number)

res = r.post(my_url, data={"customer-action": "pagination"}, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
rows = res.text.split("&&&")
for row in rows:
    html_content = ''
    try:
        array = eval(row)
        json_data = json.loads(json.dumps(array[2]))
        index = json_data["index"]
        html_content = json_data["html"]
    except:
        pass
    # Perform your research, note that some rows don't concern the products
    print(html_content)
```